# Spring Batch remote partitioning how to shutdown slaves

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to use Spring Batch remote partitioning to handle large workloads on the cloud, and spin up/shutdown VMs on demand.

However, when configuring the slave steps, I'm using the StepExecutionRequestHandler to handle the step requests from a JMS queue. Right now the application just hangs. How can I shut down the application after the queue is depleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I shut down the application after the queue is depleted?

In a remote partitioning setup, workers are listeners on a queue on which `StepExecutionRequest`s are coming. The question is how to know, from the listener point of view, that the queue is depleted? This is a tricky design problem. There are some known solutions like the "End-Of-Stream" message or "Poison" record but those are tricky too since you have to make sure all listeners get one such message.

If you are using Spring Cloud Task to launch your workers, you can use the `DeployerPartitionHandler` which provides an elegant way to dynamically create workers on demand up to a maximum configurable number. You can find more details about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#batch-partitioning and an example in this github repo: https://github.com/mminella/scaling-demos/blob/master/partitioned-demo/src/main/java/io/spring/batch/partitiondemo/configuration/BatchConfiguration.java#L75

The ice on the cake is that this is based on Spring Cloud Deployer which means you can use it on any cloud provider that implements the SCD SPI. Here is how to do it for:

- Kubernetes: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_notes_on_developing_a_batch_partitioned_application_for_the_kubernetes_platform
- cloud foundry: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_notes_on_developing_a_batch_partitioned_application_for_the_cloud_foundry_platform