# Good practice for closing workers at the same time of master with Spring Batch and Spring Integration

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-batch, partitioning

I am using Spring batch and Spring integration with remote partitioning mode.

I would like to know the best practice for closing workers at the same time of master at the end of the job.

Currently, I thought about using Topic Jms for broadcast a message to all workers for shutdown themselves in the last step on the master.

Do you have some other ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431771/spring-batch-remote-partitioning-how-to-shutdown-slaves

Comment: I don't use spring cloud (at this moment). I have posted an example of worker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54653366/11046193). If you have some ideas :)

Comment: Broadcasting a "End-Of-Work" message to workers as you suggest is a valid option IMO. Using Spring Cloud is another one. Other than that, I can't see how to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your response.